# How to replace email address with name in text using regular expressions in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

how can I replace the email addresses in a paragraph assuming it's a string now, with names ? 
like xx@yahoo.com.my = xx , .com, .ae

Input = "contact abc@yahoo.com or defg@hotmail.eu for more details"

Output = "contact Abc or Defg for more details"

Comment: your question is unclear!

Comment: you can show email in title or you can use jQuery or javascript to replace string on Hover event.

Comment: y u need regular expression for this ?

Comment: @Arun because am probably am not that good at this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're asking for a Regex, I'm going to give you one.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\.|[a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])*@(\.|[a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])*");
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(inputString))
{
    // match.Value == "xx@yahoo.com.my"
    string name = match.Groups[1]; // "xx"
    string domain = match.Groups[2]; // "yahoo.com.my"
}
```

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly I provided a `Regex`. You can do the replacing yourself. Don't be lazy.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for, as usual, feel stupid after looking at the solution :P

Comment: @TrackmeifYouCan In that case you should consider accepting the answer ;)

Comment: What worked for me was a modification of this:

Regex regex = new Regex(@"([a-zA-Z0-9\.]*)\@([a-zA-Z0-9\.]*)");

The | symbol for the OR condition did not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
int end = myString.IndexOf('@');

string name=myString.Substring(0, end);
```

Try like this.

You can refer substring function here>>

http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring

Comment: Why did you name the "end" parameter as "begin"? Odd naming convention ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sting input = "contact abc@yahoo.com or defg@hotmail.eu for more details";
String pattern = @"(\S*)@\S*\.\S*";
String result = Regex.Replace(input , pattern , "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string ReplaceEmail(string emailBody) {
        string scrubbedemailBody = emailBody;
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\.|[a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])*@(\.|[a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])*");
        scrubbedemailBody = regex.Replace(scrubbedemailBody, match => {
            return new string(' ', match.Length);
        });
        return scrubbedemailBody;
    }
```

Comment: Consider providing some explanation along with the code you provide.